# How can I install Docker on Windows 10 Home?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I knew that docker won't work on windows 10 home edition. It will work in windows 10 pro or enterprise as it need hyper v and it is available in these two. But I found some script for hyper v and able to install and enable hyper v in window 10 home. So is it better to install ubuntu as a virtual environment and install docker over there. or the windows 10 home with hyper v enabled will be good enough to install docker.
Please help me to understand this.

Thanks.

Comment: I found the wording of this a little confusing so perhaps edit it for clarity. The question you're asking is `How can I install Docker on Windows 10 Home`, right?

Comment: @JakeNelson, thanks for you response. My question was updated. still my doubt is, since windows home is previously not available for docker as it lacks hyper v then it was given wsl2 to work with. But I got the hyper v with some script. also I have installed wsl2 and configured it as default. So if docker has to run over linux environment out of wsl2 linux distro and hyper-v virtual machine which one is best to opt.

Comment: Using WSL2 native without Hyper-V is best unless you need the features of Hyper-V. In my answer, the screenshot I recorded from my Docker desktop suggests that WSL2 without Hyper-V is better performing. Can you please accept the answer if you're happy with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker does work on Windows 10 home (I'm using it now).

Install [Docker Desktop](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop) (wsl2 integration will be disabled)

[Install wsl 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install)

Restart.

Install your distro of choice through the Microsoft Store (I used Ubuntu).

Initialise Ubuntu and configure your user account.

If you run Docker in Ubuntu at this point you'll see a request to integrate with wsl2, open the Docker Desktop settings and enable integration with WSL2 for your linux distribution.

[image: WSL2 integrated with Win 10 home]